# On HP Laptop with Window 10, some keystrokes are buffered

Tags: windows-10, hp-laptop, keystrokes

Just purchased a new HP Laptop running Windows 10.  On Brave, Chrome and Notepad it ignores/buffers some keystrokes.  When I press it the first time, nothing appears to happen. When I press it again, I get two instances. I haven't tried other programs yet, so I am not sure how universal this is.

Googling suggests USB and power saving issues.  But this is the built-n keyboard.

Following characters are affected (there may be more)

- backtick
- tilde
- single quote
- double quote

Comment: What are your language and keyboard layout? It seems like this is an international layout, so that Windows is trying to combine two keystrokes into one accented character. Although it should give only one character for two repeated characters of the above.

Comment: Indeed. This is typical of "dead keys" behavior.

Comment: I had USA English and NZ English, which is what I have always had on my other machines. It called it USA International in the task bar.  I removed New Zealand but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

@harrymc was right, but it requires explanation.

- If I have only one language installed being USA then the keyboard associated with it is called **English United States International)** and the problem occurs
- If I have installed another language (in my case) English New Zealand, with US being the default, the keyboard still says **International** and the problem occurs

You have to select the other language as default in the Keyboard section, after installing that language.

- Settings
- Language
- Click on Keyboard Icon (not obvious)
- Select anything other than US International